# Cryptographic operation error with MachineKey.Unprotect

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am getting a Cryptographic operation error using the Protection function shown below, but it doesn't indicate what is going wrong.

The error is occurring on `MachineKey.Unprotect()` when I'm parsing in the bytes.

When the purpose is "username" the parse text value is `??;?W???Qzz<&???Sc??]7\\??\u001d???=?0\u007fN??g&\u001a?p?w?jJ?q?O&~c??!w???;\bv` which is converted to `byte[64]`

I have also tried UTF8 conversion from string/bytes bytes/string with the same result.

What could be causing this?

**Test Method:**

```
        var username = PasswordStorage.Protection("wheels", "username", true);
        var password = PasswordStorage.Protection("legman", "password", true);

        var decodeUN = PasswordStorage.Protection(username, "username", false);
        var decodePass = PasswordStorage.Protection(password, "password", false);
```

**Protection Method:**

```
 public static string Protection(string text, string purpose, bool protect)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return null;

            byte[] stream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            var encodedBytes = new Byte[] { };

            encodedBytes = protect ? MachineKey.Protect(stream, purpose) : MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, purpose);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // error logging omitted
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You might be losing data to control codes not round tripping well. The output of Protect should be base64, not ascii. Or just leave everything as byte[].

Comment: Okay thanks, will have a look, realised it won't work as is for what I want, due to slashes and it's being sent as a URL. However, at least that's an easy fix.